# CRM 2011 existing view filter criteria change at runtime

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to change the filter criteria of a view(MSCRM 2011) which exists in the system at run time? I do not want to add a custom view.What i want to do is to just change the filter criteria of the view at run time? Please help!!!

Comment: Are you using this view in a subgrid or in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's this if you want to apply ad-hoc filters:

http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/01/05/crm-2011-filtering-your-views-without-the-advanced-find/